# Unexpected results when using compound path to combine objects with strokes

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix this. Just finished a logo design for a client and am trying to make all of the white areas a compound path with the circle, so that it's fully transparent when overlayed on a background. The screenshot below shows the before and after. As you can see I've lost detail in the rough line inside the circle but picked up a lot of unwanted detail in the letters. Has anyone ever encountered this before? I put a yellow background behind so you can see it. Any ideas on how to fix this?
[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you had strokes applied to some (or all) of the components before you applied the compound path. If this is the case then you need to proceed as follows:

- Select the objects and go to Object > Path > Outline Stroke. This will covert the strokes to filled shapes.
- You now need to combine the outlined strokes with their objects. The easiest way to do this is using Unite in the Pathfinder palette. You may need to do some ungrouping and/or tackle each shape individually for this to work depending on how you built your artwork.
- Once you have done this for all the elements of your design, the compound path should work as expected and you will have a compound object with transparent ‘holes’ that respects your original design intent.

*Sometimes* the effect that you are seeing can be fixed by reapplying the stroke after creating the compound path, but I’m not sure if this would work in this case.

Comment: Thanks. The "after" logo was with everything created as paths and outlined strokes and united with the Pathfinder. The Opacity Mask solution worked best in this case.